# How do I prove that the limit of $\frac{x^2 y }{x^2 + y^2} = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^2 y }{x^2 + y^2} = 0$?

I can prove this by notifying $x=rcos\theta$ and $y=rsin\theta$, but I remember that it could also be proven by squeeze theorem.

How do I prove this using squeeze theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$0\le\left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le \left|\frac{x^2y}{x^2}\right|=|y|\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to (0,0)]{}0$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \leq 1$ so your function is bounded by $\pm y$.

Answer (score 2):

By AM-GM inequality we have:

$$2|xy|\leq x^2+y^2$$

So:

$$0<\frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{1}{2}$$

Multiply both sides by $|x|$:

$$0\leq \frac{|x^2y|}{x^2+y^2} \leq \frac{|x|}{2}$$

Now $\frac{|x|}{2}$ goes to zero when $(x,y) \to 0$, so $\frac{|x^2y|}{x^2+y^2}$ also goes to zero.

Comment: Nice alternative